# What is PoWhash?

Tags: mining, terminology, powhash

When I mine, I get something that says:

```
miner  22:09:05|main  Mining on PoWhash #45feeecfΓÇª : 6761650 H/s = 3407872 hashes / 0.504 s
```

What does `PoWhash` mean? I'm assuming that the `#45feeecfΓÇª` is a partial hash of the current block I'm mining?

Comment: Is it the same question as [this](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/1616/87)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PoWhash is the proof-of-work hash.

As you have assumed, you can see in the following ethminer log of a successfully mined block that the PoWhash string matches the first 7 characters of the Header-hash of the solution found:

```
miner  04:35:37.957|ethminer  Mining on PoWhash #1fe4f34a… : 62291643 H/s = 12582912 hashes / 0.202 s
miner  04:35:38.160|ethminer  Mining on PoWhash #1fe4f34a… : 41527762 H/s = 8388608 hashes / 0.202 s
  ℹ  04:35:38.391|ethminer  Solution found; Submitting to http://192.168.4.120:8545 ...
  ℹ  04:35:38.391|ethminer    Nonce: 71f8dd92f2e5d1b8
  ℹ  04:35:38.391|ethminer    Mixhash: 6010589e9b344db567a348a241fe789692115e8cebe747177b1e552986cb50d8
  ℹ  04:35:38.391|ethminer    Header-hash: 1fe4f34acda81a9c15965a66c80e7349758a0aaa1333cb85ae88d4e103d79a7f
  ℹ  04:35:38.391|ethminer    Seedhash: 63ca6f54b1af76dd4df3b908cee464ff1f212f08352cbe7eb4422806bb0c7885
  ℹ  04:35:38.391|ethminer    Target: 00000000000b1594aa498c4e48c1574062852be9a52ffa9dcfeab617ce65644a
  ℹ  04:35:38.392|ethminer    Ethash: 000000000008b905c32b3f7724a960b490618d1294822380f5db0eebeac12c86
  ℹ  04:35:38.393|ethminer  B-) Submitted and accepted.
```

Answer (score 8):

I searched the ethminer code for the string "Mining on PoWhash" and found it in libethereum/ethminer/MinerAux.h. Looking there I see this line:

`minelog << "Mining on PoWhash" << current.headerHash << ": " << mp;`

And a few lines above it:

`EthashProofOfWork::WorkPackage current;`

Based on those lines (and the way `current` is treated elsewhere in the code) I'd say that PoWhash is the hash of the header of the "work package" (or new block) ethminer is currently trying to mine. Not sure how it's being formatted there, though. Looks like it's being partially encoded as UTF-8 or ASCII or something along those lines.

Answer (score -2):

so i found a solution, and the header-hash matches the PoW. If is was solo mining would this have been a big payout? do i get a larger share of the successfully found block? i am mining on Ethereumpool.co

Comment: Welcome!  If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button.

Answer (score -3):

PoW is "Proof of Work"

According to Wikipedia:
A proof-of-work (POW) system (or protocol, or function) is an economic measure to deter denial of service attacks and other service abuses such as spam on a network by requiring some work from the service requester, usually meaning processing time by a computer. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof-of-work_system

Comment: OP is asking for `PoWhash ` not `PoW`