# Should ethminer continue mining the same PoWhash even after a solution is found?

Tags: ethminer, powhash, stratum

Is it normal for ethminer to find a solution to a problem, and even after submitting it upstream, it still continues to hash the same problem?

Here is an example:  (Genoil's ethminer in stratum mode)

`m  12:22:43|ethminer  Mining on PoWhash #c936d2df : 0.00MH/s [A37+0:R0+0:F0]
  ℹ  12:22:44|openclminer0  Solution found; Submitting to stratum-server ...
  ℹ  12:22:44|openclminer0    Nonce: 0x501061248666b5d5
  ℹ  12:22:44|stratum  B-) Submitted and accepted.
  m  12:22:44|ethminer  Mining on PoWhash #c936d2df : 29.36MH/s [A38+0:R0+0:F0]
  m  12:22:45|ethminer  Mining on PoWhash #c936d2df : 37.75MH/s [A38+0:R0+0:F0]
  m  12:22:46|ethminer  Mining on PoWhash #c936d2df : 37.75MH/s [A38+0:R0+0:F0]
  m  12:22:47|ethminer  Mining on PoWhash #c936d2df : 33.55MH/s [A38+0:R0+0:F0]
  m  12:22:48|ethminer  Mining on PoWhash #c936d2df : 41.94MH/s [A38+0:R0+0:F0]
  m  12:22:49|ethminer  Mining on PoWhash #c936d2df : 33.55MH/s [A38+0:R0+0:F0]
  m  12:22:50|ethminer  Mining on PoWhash #c936d2df : 41.94MH/s [A38+0:R0+0:F0]
  m  12:22:51|ethminer  Mining on PoWhash #c936d2df : 33.55MH/s [A38+0:R0+0:F0]
  m  12:22:52|ethminer  Mining on PoWhash #c936d2df : 41.94MH/s [A38+0:R0+0:F0]
  m  12:22:53|ethminer  Mining on PoWhash #c936d2df : 33.55MH/s [A38+0:R0+0:F0]`

Notice that even after the solution is submitted and accepted upstream, the miner continues to mine the same PoWhash #c936d2df for which it found a solution.

I inspected the network traffic and found that the problem (if there is one) is the upstream stratum pool, which accepts the request and then takes a very long time to give me another job to work on.

So the question - is the mining pool bugged?  Shouldn't it be giving me new work immediately after I find a solution?

Or is it expected that there may be multiple solutions to the same problem, and it's OK for ethminer to keep crunching numbers after finding a solution?

EDIT: This has been observed while using multiple upstream stratum pools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [PowHash is the target block header hash](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/2688/87). If you find it, you just solved a block.

A *solution found*, however, is not a new block but simply a share submitted to a mining pool. Thus, the PowHash you are working on does not change after submitting a share to the pool, but only if you are finding a block accepted by the network.

Comment: When I'm connected to `eth-proxy` I notice that it always sends me a new PoWhash to work on immediately when I submit a solution to it.  However connecting directly to a stratum server does not do this.  Is that some feature built in to `eth-proxy`, and if so then why wouldn't stratum servers want to send a new PoWhash immediately after accepting a found solution?